# How to add view with buttons (target-action) to a scroll view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, interface-builder, target-action

I have created a custom `UIViewController` with its view in a .xib file created in Interface Builder. The view looks like this:

[image]

The view has a `UIButton` with a target-action pair. The action is a method in the view's view controller. I want to add this view to a `UIScrollView`, so I created a simple custom view controller which just has as `UIScrollView` in it. I added the first view controller's view as a subview to the scrollview and set the content size properly.

Everything now works fine, except that when I press the button the application crashes and the 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS' warning comes up with error code 2.

**How can I solve this?**

Answer (score 0):

There is an action in your view controller that you assign to your button ?

Comment: Yes, I wired up the action method in Interface Builder. The target is the view controller. The pair works fine if I set the view on the picture as the root view controller.